# Parallel execution with TestNG and appium

Tags: multithreading, testng, appium

I'm currently busy with an test automation project for mobile devices and I want to store my results in a database.
I do this with a custom assertclass which I created, this one stores the result.

The layout is as following -> There are runs which contain Tests which contain Steps.

When I want to run in parallel, I create a unique id for the run based on thread and date and store this one in a static list. This is @BeforeTest.

At the @BeforeClass, I search in the list for the right thread and assign the correct name to the variable of the class.

But I receive constantly a Nullpointerexception for the list in the beforeclass or the variable is null while it was filled in in the @beforetest.

What are we missing here? Or how is this done when you need to store a parameter that is generated once for the whole run?

Thanks in advance,

Jonas Vandevelde

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I've found the issue, because of the parallel execution, the value was added to the list at like the same moment. This caused an issue sometimes because one of the two needed values was missing. I brought those 2 out of balance with a simple wait and everything works smooth now.